# Calculate number of days between two dates in r

Tags: r

I need to calculate the number of days elapsed between multiple dates in two ways and then output those results to new columns: i) number of days that has elapsed as compared to the first date (e.g., RESULTS$FIRST) and ii) between sequential dates (e.g., RESULTS$BETWEEN). Here is an example with the desired results. Thanks in advance.

```
library(lubridate)

DATA = data.frame(DATE = mdy(c("7/8/2013",  "8/1/2013", "8/30/2013", "10/23/2013", 
                                   "12/16/2013", "12/16/2015")))

RESULTS  = data.frame(DATE = mdy(c("7/8/2013",  "8/1/2013", "8/30/2013", "10/23/2013", 
                                       "12/16/2013", "12/16/2015")), 
                  FIRST = c(0, 24, 53, 107, 161, 891), BETWEEN = c(0, 24, 29, 54, 54, 730))
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
#Using dplyr package
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%  # your dataframe
mutate(BETWEEN0=as.numeric(difftime(DATE,lag(DATE,1))),BETWEEN=ifelse(is.na(BETWEEN0),0,BETWEEN0),FIRST=cumsum(as.numeric(BETWEEN)))%>%
select(-BETWEEN0)
            DATE BETWEEN FIRST
    1 2013-07-08       0     0
    2 2013-08-01      24    24
    3 2013-08-30      29    53
    4 2013-10-23      54   107
    5 2013-12-16      54   161
    6 2015-12-16     730   891
```

Comment: Thanks everyone! I should have mentioned this in the question, but I am trying to both write flexible code (e.g., the number of dates might change among data sets) and avoid for loops. So, while all the answers worked, Metrics answer appeared the most flexible. Thanks again and take care!

Answer (score 2):

This will get you what you want:

```r
d <- as.Date(DATA$DATE, format="%m/%d/%Y")

first <- c()
for (i in seq_along(d))
    first[i] <- d[i] - d[1]

between <- c(0, diff(d))
```

This uses the `as.Date()` function in the base package to cast the vector of string dates to date values using the given format. Since you have dates as month/day/year, you specify `format="%m/%d/%Y"` to make sure it's interpreted correctly.

`diff()` is the lagged difference. Since it's lagged, it doesn't include the difference between element 1 and itself, so you can concatenate a 0.

Differences between `Date` objects are given in days by default.

Then constructing the output dataframe is simple:

```r
RESULTS <- data.frame(DATE=DATA$DATE, FIRST=first, BETWEEN=between)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first part:

```
DATA = data.frame((c("7/8/2013",  "8/1/2013", "8/30/2013", "10/23/2013","12/16/2013", "12/16/2015")))
names(DATA)[1] = "V1"
date = as.Date(DATA$V1, format="%m/%d/%Y")
print(date-date[1])
```

Result:

```
[1]   0  24  53 107 161 891
```

For second part - simply use a `for` loop

Answer (score 0):

You can just add each column with the simple `difftime` and lagged `diff` calculations.

```
DATA$FIRST <- c(0, 
                with(DATA, 
                     difftime(DATE[2:length(DATE)],DATE[1], unit="days")
                     )
                )
DATA$BETWEEN <- c(0, 
                  with(DATA, 
                       diff(DATE[1:(length(DATE) - 1)], unit="days")
                       )
                  )

identical(DATA, RESULTS)
[1] TRUE
```